# yii modal dialog login

Tags: authentication, yii, modal-dialog

I've been looking all over the internet and I can't seem to find the solution to just a simple login via header. I tried all sorts of way. The problem I have right now just reloads every time i hit login. It's only when I go to ?r=site/login it'll let me login. Is there some kind of controller for headers!??! Not sure what is wrong anymore.

Right now i have this in my header:

```
 <?php $this->beginWidget(
'bootstrap.widgets.TbModal',
 array('id' => 'login')
); ?>

<?php 
$model=new LoginForm;
$this->renderPartial('//site/login', array('model'=>$model));
?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

//stuff here
          <?php $this->widget(
        'bootstrap.widgets.TbButton',
        array(
            'label' => 'Signin',
            'type' => 'warning',
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'data-toggle' => 'modal',
                'data-target' => '#login',
            ),
        )
    );
?>
```

And then in site/login:

```
    <div class="spacing">
<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'login-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
)); ?>
<div class="form" id="login-form">
<div class="login-container">
  <div class="login-header">
    <h1 title="login">Sign In</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="login-form">
    <div class="input-position">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Email',array('class'=>'span3','style'=>'text-align:left')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email', array('class'=>'span3')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="input-position">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password',array('class'=>'span3','style'=>'text-align:left')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('class'=>'span3',)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="input-position  ">
        <div class="rememberMe">
        <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->label($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
    </div>
      </div>

        <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login'); ?>
        </div>
        <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

    </div>

  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

controller

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model=new LoginForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if($model->validate() && $model->login())
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific on describing your issue? its hard to get an exact understanding of your problem.

Comment: I am just trying to login via the header using modal. There's probably many ways to do it, but I think what I have is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, please keep your login script inside some loop like this to escape it from reloading every time.

```
if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest and (Yii::app()->controller->id=='site' and Yii::app()->controller->action->id = 'login')){
  $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array('id' => 'login')); 
  ---
  $this->endWidget();
}else{
  // keep some log out or other script here. 
}
```

Comment: Still can't login, but it doesn't reload anymore.

Comment: Oh ! please enclose your view/site/login.php with html form tag. I mean $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(... )) and $this->endWidget(). OR <form action="/site/login" method="post">---</form>

Answer (score 0):

Here is the login what i have implemented on Modal login style:

**Component/Header:**

```
<?php 
Yii::import('zii.widgets.CPortlet');

class Header extends CPortlet
{
  protected function renderContent()
 {

    $this->render('Header');
   }
}
```

**Components/view/Header.php**

```
 <?php if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest){?>
    <?php echo TbHtml::link('<i class="sign-in"></i>Sign in', '#', array(
                                        'data-toggle' => 'modal',
                                        'data-target' => '#loginModal',
                                        ));?>
<?php } else{ echo 'Hi!'.$user; } ?>
```

**In View/Layout/Main.php**

```
<?php 
 $model = new LoginForm;
 $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array(
'id' => 'loginModal',
'header' => '<h3 id="loginModal">Sign In</h3>',
'content'=> $this->renderPartial('userlogin',array('model'=>$model),true),
'remote' => $this->createUrl('site/userlogin'),
'onShow'=>'function(){$("#login-form")[0].reset(); }',
 'show'=>false,)); ?>
```

**View/Site/Userlogin.php**

```
<?php  $form = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'login-form',
    //'helpType'=>'help-none',
      'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('userlogin'), 
      //'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
'clientOptions' => array(
        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
        'validateOnChange'=>false,
        'afterValidate' => 'js:function(form, data, hasError) {
            if (!hasError){
                str = $("#login-form").serialize() + "&ajax=login-form";

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "' . Yii::app()->createUrl('site/userlogin') . '",
                    data: str,
                    dataType: "json",
                    beforeSend : function() {
                        $("#login").attr("disabled",true);
                    },
                    success: function(data, status) {
                        if(data.authenticated)
                        {
                            window.location = data.redirectUrl;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                                var div = "#"+key+"_em_";
                                $(div).text(value);
                                $(div).show();
                            });
                            $("#login").attr("disabled",false);
                        }
                    },
                });
                return false;
            }
        }',
    ),
));?>
<?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'username',array('span'=>5,'maxlength'=>255,'required'=>true)); ?>
   <?php echo $form->passwordFieldControlGroup($model,'password',array('span'=>5,'maxlength'=>255,'required'=>true)); ?>
<?php echo TbHtml::submitbutton('Sign In',array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')); ?>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

This will Authenticate via Ajax

**SiteController:**

```
$model=new LoginForm;

                // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        $errors = CActiveForm::validate($model);
        if ($errors != '[]')
                        {
                            echo $errors;
                            Yii::app()->end();
                        }
    }
if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];

        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if ($model->validate() && $model->login()) {
                                if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'login-form') {
$user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
                                    $arr = array();
                                    $record = Users::model()->findByPk($user_id);
 if ($record) {
echo CJSON::encode(array( 'authenticated' => true,
'redirectUrl' => CController::createUrl('users/trainerprofile'),
"id" => $record->id,));
  Yii::app()->end();
   }
}
```